# What are some of the ways to deal with missing data when measuring extreme poverty?

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

The UNDP have [report](http://www.un.org/millenniumgoals/pdf/report-2013/mdg-report-2013-english.pdf)ed that the millennium goal of halving the percentage of people living below 1 USD (PPP) a day has been met (compared to 1990). I was looking at [the data](http://mdgs.un.org/unsd/mdg/Data.aspx) for that indicator and there were a lot of missing values. Some of the countries doesn't even have values for the first ten years (1990–2000). I was then wondering, what are some of the ways to deal with this, in this particular situation? Do you, for example, calculate the mean progress within the given country over a period of time and add estimates based on that, or is there a more sophisticated way?

Comment: If the answers sought require specific substantive knowledge of poverty studies, this would be better placed in some other forum, although I can't advise which. If this is asking about missing data, look for many questions on this site, as the specific details here obscure your statistical question.